# World Bank lending categories

Tags: banking

I need to do data visualization of World Bank lending category for some countries using source from their page. When I was going through it I found some inconsistencies in categories they use to describe lending groups. According to the World Bank we have three lending group:

- IBRD,
- IDA,
- BLEND

but to describe other data they used following markers:

- IDA only  - IDX,
- IDA total - IDA,
- IDA Blend - IDB,
- IBRD only - IBD,
- IDA & IBR TOTAL - IBT

Which of the three lending group correspond to six following markers? I mean is IBRD same as IBD (IBRD only), etc?

Source [[1]](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/906519-world-bank-country-and-lending-groups) and [[2]](http://databank.worldbank.org/data/download/site-content/CLASS.xls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this](https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/378834-how-does-the-world-bank-classify-countries) page states:

> International Development Association (IDA) countries are those with low per capita incomes that lack the financial ability to borrow from the International Bank for Reconstruction and Development (IBRD). Blend countries are eligible for IDA loans but are also eligible for IBRD loans because they are financially creditworthy.

Therefore the classification of countries can be representd with the following Venn diagram:

[image]

The final category, `IBT`, compromises `IDA + IDBR`, equivalent to `IDX + IDB + IBD`.

Note: this is **my interpretation**, and not based on an official definition (which I couldn't find).